Why same query is less performant on better machine?
Background
I have two virtual machines set up on Azure:

Standard E48ds v5
Standard E16ds v5

Both machines are running SQL Server 2019, and I have a specific query that retrieves data from a view. The body of the view consists solely of heaps (+ 1 small table from different DB). However, I’ve noticed that executing the same query on these two different VM configurations results in significantly different execution plans, and the plan generated by the E16ds v5 appears to be more efficient.
Plan on Standard E16ds v5 (query finished in 13 minutes):
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B11RudaV1x
Plan on Standard E48ds v5 (query was running 1h 20 minutes and not finished - live execution plan was retrieved)
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rytCY_aNyl

Why we have such difference ?


The plans are large, but the critical difference appears to be that the more capable machine uses a plan that features Batch mode on Rowstore (BMoR).
This is generally a performance-boosting feature, but certain operations can be much slower in adverse circumstances. In particular, hash and sort spills can be slow.
Spills occur when not enough memory is allocated for a hash table or sorting operation. The memory allocation depends on cardinality estimates. The estimates in your complex plan are quite inaccurate in places. The allocation between concurrently executing operators (usually multiple hashes) can also be problematic in batch mode.
The query likely needs detailed expert tuning, but if you are in a hurry to eliminate BMoR as a cause try the documented query hint:
OPTION(USE HINT('DISALLOW_BATCH_MODE'));

